# converting ZonedDateTime to Calendar using ThreeTen-Backport (JSR 310)

Tags: calendar, zoneddatetime, jsr310, threetenbp

I am trying to convert a `ZonedDateTime` object to a `Calendar` object using the back-port of the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes ([JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)): the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

My understanding was that the back-port was supposed to be similar to functionality on Java 8 (without being on Java 8 itself). Currently, the system is on Java 7.

Whenever I try to execute the following code:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ....
GregorianCalendar newCal = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt);
```

I get the following message:

> The method from(ZonedDateTime) is undefined for the type
>   GregorianCalendar

I used the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
    <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

How can one come about this problem?

Any help hints or advice would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils`

The backport cannot add methods to the JDK. See [DateTimeUtils](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html) for the conversion methods.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ....
GregorianCalendar newCal = DateTimeUtils.toGregorianCalendar(zdt);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not see that :-)